# JQueryでラベル要素の内容を変更したい

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var totalval = $(".car_model option:selected").val()
var strtext = totalval.split("|");
var tcd = strtext[0];
var tname = strtext[1];

window.opener.document.getElementById("tcd").value = tcd;
window.opener.document.getElementById("tname").value = tname;　// <-　Label
```

ラベル要素の内容はValueでは捉えられないようで変更できません。どう対応すべきですか？
１行目はテキストボックスなので、無事変更できました。

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">受注先</td>
    <td class="extd"><button class="tcdsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png"></td>
    <td class="extd" style="width:9999px"><input type="text" name="tcd" id="tcd" style="width:45px;"><label name="tname" id="tname"></label><label name="ttelno" id="ttelno"></label></td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: tcd / tname のHTMLソースも示してください。for属性で関連付けしている場合とタグの入れ子で関連付けしている場合で対処が異なります。

Comment: すみません、超初心者で、問い合わせ枠にHTMLを入力できず　こちらにいれさせてもらいました、見難いようであれば大変申し訳ないです。待ち受けのHTML側　追記します
<table>
<tr>
<td rowspan="3">受注先</td>
<td class="extd"><button class="tcdsrch" type="button"><img src="img/検索.png"></td>
<td class="extd" style="width:9999px"><input type="text" name="tcd" id="tcd" style="width:45px;"><label name="tname" id="tname"></label><label name="ttelno" id="ttelno"></label></td>
</tr>

Comment: その構造であれば、豚吐露さんの回答のままでうまくいくのではないかと思います。ただ、これだとlabel要素を使うメリットがあまりなさそうですね。普通はlabel要素とコントロール要素を関連付けて、label要素のクリック/タッチでコントロール要素に作用するようにします。

Comment: int32さん　貴重なご見解をありがとうございます。今後の開発上のノウハウに役立ちそうです。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get

```
$("label#tname").text();
```

set

```
$("label#tname").text("hogehoge");
```

Comment: window.opener.document.getElementById("tname").innerHTML= tname;でうまくできました。ブラウザ依存の解決方法でないことを祈るばかり